# A way to convert json field which is not always the same type using Json.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am working with some api that returns JSON containing a field ID, but this field could be int array or object (let`s call it SomeObject) array.

```
//int[]
[JsonProperty("id")] public int[] ID { get; set; }
//SomeObject[]
[JsonProperty("id")] public SomeObject[] ID { get; set; }

//my guess of handling unknown type?
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyOwnConverter))]
[JsonProperty("id")] public Wrapper ID { get; set; }


class Wrapper {
     int[] IdArray {
         get => IdArray;
         set {
             IdArray = value;
             IsId = true;
         }
     }
     SomeObject[] ObjectArray {
         get => ObjectArray;
         set {
             ObjectArray = value;
             IsId = false;
         }
     }
     bool IsId { get; set; }
}
```

I understand how to handle each of data type separately (like in code above), when i know what type i am receiving. What should i do to make it work when i do not know the type of data? I was trying to implement custom JsonConverter, and use Wrapper class to store either int or SomeObject but failed at it. Any hints how to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome Joshua - I tend to use the `JObject` class and do either `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>` or `JObject.Parse()` and then you can treat the json like a dictionary, so you can do `parsedObject["someProp"].ToObject<>` or `parsedObject["someProp"].ToString`

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm#ID8RBSection

Comment: @CallumLinington Using `JObject` will work. Thank You.